# How to use 2 condition(connected with AND) in COUNTIF function?

Tags: excel, numbers, countif

#### Q1:

Count how many rows contain **BOTH** `C` and `D` in `F::2:11`

#### Q2:

Count how many rows **ONLY** contain `C` in `F::2:11`

```
╔════╦═════╦════╦════╦════╦════╦═════╗
║    ║  A  ║ B  ║ C  ║ D  ║ E  ║  F  ║
╠════╬═════╬════╬════╬════╬════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ ID# ║ Q1 ║ Q2 ║ Q3 ║ Q4 ║ Q5  ║
║  2 ║ 101 ║ E  ║ D  ║ D  ║ C  ║ CD  ║
║  3 ║ 105 ║ C  ║ B  ║ B  ║ C  ║ C   ║
║  4 ║ 102 ║ D  ║ D  ║ D  ║ D  ║ DEC ║
║  5 ║ 104 ║ C  ║ D  ║ B  ║ D  ║ C   ║
║  6 ║ 107 ║ D  ║ C  ║    ║    ║ ACD ║
║  7 ║ 106 ║ D  ║ C  ║    ║ C  ║ D   ║
║  8 ║ 109 ║ C  ║ D  ║ A  ║ C  ║ D   ║
║  9 ║ 111 ║ E  ║ B  ║ B  ║ E  ║ AC  ║
║ 10 ║ 121 ║ D  ║ B  ║    ║ C  ║ DB  ║
║ 11 ║ 115 ║ C  ║ C  ║ C  ║ C  ║ BC  ║
╚════╩═════╩════╩════╩════╩════╩═════╝
```

#### I want to use:

`COUNTIF(F::2:11,  )` function.

#### Expected result:

For Q1: `3`
For Q2: `7`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For both C & D in F2:F11,

```
=countifs(F2:F11, "*C*", F2:F11, "*D*")
```

For just D in F2:F11,

```
=countif(F2:F11, "*D*")
```

Comment: There is one small problem: if i use `=countif(F2:F11, "*D*")`, Rows like `CD` are also counted. I want this cases are excluded.

Comment: I see, solution is: `=countifs(F2:F11, "*C*", F2:F11, "<>*D*")`

Comment: Remove the wildcards